# i want to join several tables with another one, but i get back 0 rows as result

Tags: mysql

My EER-Modell [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNYwB.jpg).

Do I have to do a sub section and an inner join?
My query

```
SELECT mounting_system_type, positions.id , positions.module_count as mp, configurations.position_id, module_blocks.id ,module_blocks.module_count as Anzahl_pro_Block,
ballast as ballast_pro_Modulblock, dead_weight as EGG_pro_Block, dead_load as pro_Block, obstacles.height,
obstacles.module_area_offset, obstacles.shape_type, roof_zone
FROM base.positions
join configurations on positions.id = configurations.position_id
join module_blocks on configurations.id = module_blocks.configuration_id
join roof_zones on configurations.id = roof_zones.configuration_id
join obstacles on positions.id = obstacles.position_id
group by module_blocks.id
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no such thing as `FROM base.positions`, you specify a table `FROM positions`.

You can read about [JOIN'S here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/). You where just adding fields without specifying where do they come from. Next time also provide an error you are getting.

```
SELECT positions.mounting_system_type, positions.id , positions.module_count as mp, configurations.position_id, module_blocks.id ,module_blocks.module_count as Anzahl_pro_Block,
module_blocks.ballast as ballast_pro_Modulblock, module_blocks.dead_weight as EGG_pro_Block, module_blocks.dead_load as pro_Block, obstacles.height,
obstacles.module_area_offset, obstacles.shape_type, roof_zone.roof_zone
FROM positions
join configurations on positions.id = configurations.position_id
join module_blocks on configurations.id = module_blocks.configuration_id
join roof_zones on configurations.id = roof_zones.configuration_id
join obstacles on positions.id = obstacles.position_id
group by module_blocks.id
```

In case your  wanted roof_zone is from module_fields_roof_zones table (you have roof_zone in two tables):

```
 SELECT positions.mounting_system_type, positions.id , positions.module_count as mp, configurations.position_id, module_blocks.id ,module_blocks.module_count as Anzahl_pro_Block,
    module_blocks.ballast as ballast_pro_Modulblock, module_blocks.dead_weight as EGG_pro_Block, module_blocks.dead_load as pro_Block, obstacles.height,
    obstacles.module_area_offset, obstacles.shape_type, module_fields_roof_zones.roof_zone
    FROM positions
    join configurations on positions.id = configurations.position_id
    join module_blocks on configurations.id = module_blocks.configuration_id
    join roof_zones on configurations.id = roof_zones.configuration_id
    join module_fields_roof_zones on configurations.id = module_fields_roof_zones.configuration_id
    join obstacles on positions.id = obstacles.position_id
    group by module_blocks.id
```

Try this and see if there any errors or results.

Comment: I get no error, the result of the query is 0 row(s) returnded

Comment: @user12272594 did you try with other type of joins?

Comment: i try now with left join